# Change time interval

Tags: javascript, time, countdown, intervals

How can I change or countdown my time interval? I want to popup "alert" every 5000ms, 4000ms, 3000ms, and so on.

```
intervall = 5000;

setInterval(function(){

  alert("ALERT");

  interval = interval - 1000;      
},intervall);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using setTimeout instead of setInterval.

Like this:

```
interval = 5000;

setTimeout(function(){

  alert("ALERT");

  interval = interval - 1000;      
},interval);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Have you a snippet for me?

Comment: I updated my answer with an example. I also fixed the variable name since you had interval and intervall (two ls).